# Passing data to different view/template - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just started with AngularJS, So my question might be very basic.

I have a link in one view, which once clicked calls a service, gets the data. In the controller i am changing the view using $location and updating the new view with the data i got from service. The view is changing fine, But i am having issue updating the data. Below is my code.

**First View:**

```
<a class="red"  ng-href='#RestaurantDetails' ng-click='restaurantDetails()'>
   {{restaurant.name}}
</a>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.restaurantDetails = function()
{
    fpServices.loadRestaurantDetails(function(event){
        $scope.restaurantInfo = event;
        $scope.restaurantId = event[0].id;
        $location.path('/restaurant_details/'+$scope.restaurantId);
    });
};
```

*'restaurantInfo'* is an object i am getting from service.

**Second View:**

```
{{restaurantInfo.name}}
```

Tried ng-repeat too with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are setting you content on the first view scope you cannot access it from a different view scope.

What you can do is use the `$rootScope` and set the property like `activeRestaurant` such as

`$rootScope.activeRestaurant=event;`

and then can access this in the other view. Remember to inject $rootScope in both the views.

The better way would be to create a service, to set active restaurant and call it from one view to set the restaurant and from another to get the active restaurant.

Comment: Setting $rootScope worked like a charm!..Thanks @Chandermani.